# Excel-vba How to make macro replace 5 last character and add it into new column until last row

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to Add an Value from B2 and then change 5 last digit to "*" and put it in column c2 until last row. But I always get an error.

```
    B                    C
 3321072204140001   332107220414*****
```

I'm trying this

```
Sub Macro3()
 Sheets("Sheet1").Select
     Range(Range("O2"), Range("O" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Select
Selection.Formula = "=REPLACE(B2,13,4,"*****")"
    Selection.Columns.AutoFit    
End Sub
```

Can you please let me know the correct code? Thanks :)

Comment: Please improve your Markdown formatting, the beginning of the question does not make sense.

Comment: In your question you say 5 characters, but in your example, you are only swapping 4 characters.

Comment: Thank u for answer...  but result just appear 2 rows value not until last rows. but  i use Range("C2:C" & Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Formula = "=left(B2,len(B2)-5) & ""*****"""
Range("C2:C" & Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Copy
Range("C2:C" & Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues and It Works

Answer (score 1):

Three issues in your code

1. Missing escaping of `"` 's
2. Your math is wrong.  (Code based on replacing **Last 5** characters as per Q title)
3. Unnecessary use of `Select`

---

```
Sub Macro3()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    With ws
        .Range(.Range("O2"), .Range("O" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Formula = _
          "=REPLACE(B2,LEN(B2)-4,5,""*****"")"
        .Columns.AutoFit
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, where the string to be modified is in **Col B** and the modified string is in **Col C** (values will be side by side).
I'm using **Col B** to determine last row here, although it looks like you were using **Col O**. Not sure if that is a typo or intentional. Either way, update that line as needed.

```
Sub Macro3()

Dim WS As Worksheet
Set WS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

Dim LRow As Long, i as Long, MyString As String, NewString As String, StrLen as Integer
LRow = WS.Range("B" & WS.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To LRow                                           'Loop through all B strings (header excluded)
    MyString = WS.Range("B" & i)                               'Variable just to make steps easier to read
    StrLen = Len(MyString) - 5                             'Resize String
    NewString = Trim(Left(MyString, StrLen)) & "*****"     'Remove unwanted spaces, remove last 5, add new 5
    WS.Range("C" & i) = NewString                           'Assign to your range
Next i

WS.Range("B:C").EntireColumn.AutoFit

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank u for answer...  but result just appear 2 rows value not until last rows. but  i use Range("C2:C" & Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Formula = "=left(B2,len(B2)-5) & ""*****"""
Range("C2:C" & Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Copy
Range("C2:C" & Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues and It Works

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be with code?

You can use a formula `=left(B2,len(B2)-5)&"*****"`

alternatively you can do it through code then copy and paste the values:

```
Range("C2:C" & Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Formula = "=left(B2,len(B2)-5) & ""*****"""
Range("C2:C" & Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Copy
Range("C2:C" & Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Comment: standing applause for u :D